# How can I unpublish/delete a comment of an Facebook Ad?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I need a solution where I can unpublish/delete comments on Facebook Ads. There are paid tools which have this feature, like this one:

https://www.agorapulse.com/blog/comments-facebook-dark-unpublished-posts

> "Finding and responding to these comments was a major headache, so we
>   went digging on Facebook’s API and found a solution to include all
>   comments made on dark/Unpublished posts and we included them in our
>   unified Facebook Inbox."

With the normal command endpoint I can't get the commands for ads.

How I can access and manage the commands, which API endpoints I need?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few endpoints you'll most likely be interested in:

1) Your ads are connected to a page, so you'll need to get data for your Page. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/managing for reference.

2) Your page contains the posts. See the section titled "Getting Page Posts" in the link from step 1.

3) The posts contain comments. Using the id of the post, make the appropriate API calls to get its posts. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/object/comments/ for reference.

4) Once you find the comment you want to delete, make the appropriate DELETE call on it. See graph-api/reference/v2.9/comment/ for reference.